# C++ Stringstream: Accepts a string, but not a string stored in a variable. Why?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I've been trying to split up an input string into smaller strings delineated by whitespace. I found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325042):

```
stringstream ss ("bla bla");
string s;

while (getline(ss, s, ' ')) {
cout << s << endl;
}
```

which works just fine. However, if I replace "bla bla" with a variable containing a string:

```
string userInput;
cin >> userInput;

stringstream ss (userInput);
string s;

while (getline(ss, s, ' ')) {
cout << s << endl;
}
```

only the first word/char/string prints out. Why is that? Is there a way to fix it? I've looked around at some stringstream questions, but the problem is that I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Comment: Please show an example of "a variable containing a string" and initializing the `stringstream` with that.

Comment: Looks ok to me: http://ideone.com/1AvVV.

Comment: Either don't use `cin ` to initialise `userInput` so you can focus on `getline`, or investigate just what `cin >> userInput;` does, without worrying about `getline`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Really? Could it be a compiler issue then? I was working in Code::Blocks 10.05. I'll pull another IDE real quick and try it then.

Comment: @user1258934 It's not the compiler - it's you. The problem is with `cin`. Just test that bit of code to understand how `cin` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem isn't `stringstream ss (userInput);`, it's the behavior of `std::cin`. Any whitespace will end the extraction of formatted user input, so the input `bla bla` will result in *one* `std::string s = "bla"` and another string `"bla"` waiting for extraction.

<strike>Use `cin >> noskipws  >> userInput;` instead.</strike> If you want to get a line, use `std::getline(std::cin,userInput)` instead. Have a look at this little [demonstration](http://ideone.com/BOpaC), which compares `std::getline` to `std::cin::operator>>` on your input `bla bla`:

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
        std::string userInput;

        std::cout << "Using std::getline(std::cin,userInput) on input \"bla bla\"." << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin,userInput);
        std::cout << "userInput contains \"" << userInput << "\"" << std::endl;

        std::cout << "std::cin >> userInput on input \"bla bla\"." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> userInput;
        std::cout << "userInput contains \"" << userInput << "\"" << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Using std::getline(std::cin,userInput) on input "bla bla".
userInput contains "bla bla"
std::cin >> userInput on input "bla bla".
userInput contains "bla"
```

See also:

- [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) from `<string>` ([alternative resource](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)).
- <strike>[`noskipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/)</strike> (This will only prevent skipping *leading* whitespaces, a whitespace will still terminate the extraction).
- <strike>[`istream::operator>>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)</strike>

Comment: You sir/madam, are a Godsend. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1258934 AAAhhhh I was testing with "blabla", not "bla bla", that's why it worked. +1

Comment: @user1258934: I updated my answer, since I described the behavior but provided a dull solution. I mean, come on, `std::noskipws`? I shouldn't answer any questions without coffee :D... But I guess you already solved the rest (`std::getline`) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you said:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string test("bla bla");
    std::stringstream stream(test);
    std::string temp;
    while (getline(stream, temp, ' ')) {
       std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is even what you said you did. But since it works - where is the difference to your code?

And for those who do not have a Microsoft Visual C++ compiler handy and do not understand the differences, here's a code snippet:

```
std::string test("bla bla");
std::stringstream stream(test);
std::string temp;
while (getline(stream, temp, ' ')) {
   std::cout << temp << std::endl;
}
```

the includes required by that snippet are: `<string>`, `<sstream>` & `<iostream>`. Please insert it into the required method.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it is better to present standard C++, rather than Microsoftized C++ (`stdafx.h`, `_tmain`, `_TCHAR`)...

Comment: @Chalesworth: I'd agree if the code that matters requires changes to run on a different compiler - but in this case it does not (see modification of the post). I wanted to post an example that I compiled and tested.